# "I have had it for a long time" or "I had it for a long time"?

Tags: grammar, present-perfect, past-simple

Let's say you sold your car 1 year ago.

Would you say:

> I'm sad I sold my car. **I have had it** for a long time.

Or just

> I'm sad I sold my car. **I had it** for a long time.

Are they both correct?
I thought only the last one is correct because he doesn't have the car anymore, hence there is no connection to the present.

Comment: Both are fine if the sale just happened. But if it's been months or years since the sale of the car, you would not say *have had*, you would just say *had*. That's because it's something that clearly happened in the distant past. Even though the replacement in the sentence doesn't work, think of *have had* as *just had*. (*Have had* is also appropriate if you *still* have it.)

Answer (score -1):

Both are grammatically correct, but mean different things. "*I have had it for a long time*" means that you *still have it*.

So in the case of your sold car, you would be correct to say:

> I'm sad I sold my car. I had it for a long time.

... unless you had agreed on the sale and the car was still in your possession - in that scenario you might speak of it as if it was still there.